# Problem with Android Navigation: Multiple back stacks

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigationview, android-navigation-graph, android-navigation-bar

My problem is when I try to change the fragment with the bottom navigation it works except in one case. I have 5 fragments, when I enter in the 3rd and after go to the 5th, the icon of the 5th don´t change it color. After that when I do another navigation the APP crash and give me the next error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: fromIndex = -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1014)
    at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:1008)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.popBackStack(FragmentNavigator.kt:80)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.popBackStackInternal(NavController.kt:275)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.popBackStackInternal(NavController.kt:558)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1682)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1541)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1468)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.kt:92)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupWithNavController$lambda-6(NavigationUI.kt:602)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.$r8$lambda$6wzEv9QqEZKdQFS1sQQy-bdQvgE(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onNavigationItemSelected(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationBarView.java:295)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView$1.onClick(NavigationBarMenuView.java:133)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7520)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7489)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:826)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28555)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

But if previously i clicked in the 5th fragment and go to the 3rd and after 5th again it works correctly.

For my code I follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f)  and the code are the same in both cases.

edit: Here is my code to add the navigation in MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        setupBottomNavigationBar()
    }
private fun setupBottomNavigationBar(){
     val graphs = setOf(
            R.id.firstFragment,
            R.id.secondFragment,
            R.id.thirdFragment,
            R.id.fourthFragment,
            R.id.fithFragment
     )
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_container) as NavHostFragment

    currentNavController = navHostFragment.navController

    val bottomNavigation = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
    bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(currentNavController)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(graphs)
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/super_nav"
    />
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/botton_navigation_colors"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:itemIconSize="35dp"
    />
```

bottom_nav.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/first_navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_first_black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/first_desc"
    android:title="@string/first_title" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/second_navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_second"
    android:contentDescription="@string/second_desc"
    android:title="@string/second_title" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/third_navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_third"
    android:contentDescription="@string/third_desc"
    android:title="@string/third_title" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/fourth_navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_fourth"
    android:contentDescription="@string/fourth_desc"
    android:title="@string/fourth_title" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/fifth_navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_fifth"
    android:contentDescription="@string/fifth_desc"
    android:title="@string/fifth_title" />
```

And super_nav.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/super_nav"
app:startDestination="@+id/main_navigation">

<include app:graph="@navigation/first_navigation"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/second_navigation"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/third_navigation" />
<include app:graph="@navigation/fourth_cart_navigation" />
<include app:graph="@navigation/fifth_navigation" />
```

Comment: You should [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828&template=1093757) with a sample project that reproduces your issue.

Comment: without showing code giving answer not possible . your code has mistake .. try to show  code

Comment: @Gray, Have you find solution?

Answer (score 4):

I've just fixed very similar issue. The problem in my case was that I had destinations with the same id in several navigation subgraphs.
I mean:

```
<include app:graph="@navigation/first_sub_graph"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/second_sub_graph"/>

<navigation
    android:id="@+id/first_sub_graph"
    ..>

    ...
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/**destinationID_1**"
        ...
    />
</navigation>

<navigation
    android:id="@+id/second_sub_graph"
    ..>

    ...
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/**destinationID_1**"
        ...
    />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've spent 4 hours finding the reason

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this with 2.5.3 navigation library but works fine with latest (2.7.2)